# background a react-native android app using back button

Tags: android, react-native, back-button

I've followed the example pattern for handling the android back button in the react-native [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backandroid.html) and it works well. I can use the hardware back button to pop my navigation stack.

At the point that there's only 1 view in the stack though I don't pop it (just like the example), and I return *false* from my `hardwareBackPress` event listener.  At this point it I see the `componentWillUnmount` method being called in my final view, at which point my app shuts down.

If I return *true* then nothing happens at all obviously.

What I want to happen is that the app merely gets "backgrounded" instead of exiting completely.

Comment: Ya, am facing the same issue.. I have a login page, moved to forgot password page, now I clicked back navigator popped to login. In login again I clicked back button it is not closing app. I don't know why. help me with this if you know the answer.

Comment: I'm facing the opposite issue. My app gets backgrounded and I want to shut it down on back button press. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45191413/react-native-application-does-not-shut-down-on-back-button

Answer (score 11):

Answered my own question.  The trick is to override the default back button behaviour in the `MainActiviy`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "foo";
    }

    @Override
    public void invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
        // do not call super. invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() as it will close the app.  Instead lets just put it in the background.
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting nuts to find out how to recompile (the java part) after this change, I would be glad about a hint here. Just have to do that too rarely.

Comment: and again, it did recompile all the time using `react-native run-android` but seems the `moveTaskToBack` does not do what it should ... #investigating

Comment: Wolfram Kriesing - Maybe it's a problem with the version of android you're coding to?  What version is it?

Comment: @pomo I am using RN 0.59 and this seemed to work, but not always. Then I found out that every time I reinstall the app this doesn't work in the first time. When I terminate the app and restart it, it is starting to work until next reinstall. I found this, not sure if it is related to my problem: stackoverflow.com/a/39805305/5532513 (continued in next comment)

Comment: Adding @C-lioGarcia (continued from previous comment) have you encountered any similar issue? Do you think that adding restart() will solve it? Do I need to call it when my app is starting? Should restart() be identical to the code in the link posted in the previous comment?

Comment: I opened a new issue for my two last comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58712153/moving-a-react-native-android-app-to-the-background-using-back-button-fails-ever

Comment: Thanks! Works in RN 0.63.4. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/6e6443afd04a847ef23fb6254a84e48c70b45896/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactActivity.java#L94

Answer (score 6):

Though I may be very late in giving the answer it may help other facing the issue.

Recently I came across the same requirement where I have to move the app to the background. I tried the solution provided by @pomo. Though it worked I faced problems. Sometimes on multiple clicking of the back button, the app misbehaves in android though it worked perfectly fine in iOS.

And then I came across the following issues in GitHub where it mentions the reason for the misbehaviour.

The following solution works perfectly fine now.

```java
// android/app/.../MainActivity.java
@Override
public void invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

```xml
<!-- AndroidManifest.xml -->
<activity
    ...
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
```

[Link from where I get the solution](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13775#issuecomment-319673305)

I hope I'm able to help guys with the same requirement.