# React-native application does not shut down on back button

Tags: android, back-button, react-native, expo

My react-native application (on Android) does not shut down when back button is pressed. It closes and goes in the background and runs there (animates).

I also tried this, but got the same outcome:

```
BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {

  console.log('back pressed');
  BackHandler.exitApp();
});
```

**I want it to completely shut down when I press back or home button.**

P.S. I'm using Expo for development and deployment, and also start the app through it.

Comment: Seems BackAndroid.exitApp () will not kill the App's process i think

Comment: As I see it just puts it to background

Comment: have you try to put it on `componentDidMount()` method ?

Comment: No. But it get's run on back button pressed. I will now try: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-exit-app. Actually I wont, you have to mess up with gradle and java stuff

Comment: i have the same problem with you, but after i put the `BackHandler` inside `componentDidMount()` method, i can solve my problem, but it's oke if you want to use that package

Comment: In componentDidMount of which component? Toplevel App.js?

Comment: in component that you use your `BackHandler`

Comment: Didnt help. BackHandler gets called as before, but just put's app in background.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149609/discussion-between-croraf-and-rizal-sidik).

Answer (score 0):

```
 constructor(props) {
                   super(props);
                   this.handleBackButtonClick = this.handleBackButtonClick.bind(this);
                 }

                 componentWillMount() {
                   BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
                 }

                 componentWillUnmount() {
                   BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
                 }

                 handleBackButtonClick() {
                   BackHandler.exitApp();
                 }
```